# Url path construction in Angular

Tags: angular, url, routes

I am using Angular 8 and Django 3. I do not understand the way that my url path is being built in Angular. I have a `restaurantlist` component and a `restaurantdetail` component with the following paths in my `app-routing-module.ts`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'restaurantlist', component:RestaurantlistComponent},
  {path:'restaurantdetail/:id', component:RestaurantViewComponent}
];
```

In my `restaurantlist.component.html` file:

```
<h2>List of Restaurants</h2>
<ul *ngFor = "let restaurant of restaurants">
<a [routerLink]="['restaurantdetail', restaurant.id]">{{restaurant.name}}</a>  
</ul>
```

When I go to click on one of the links in my `restaurant.component.html` file, the link that it tries to send me to is `localhost:4200\restaurantlist\restaurantdetail\2`. I dont want this, I want it to send me to `localhost:4200\restaurantdetail\2`, since this is how I have my django urls set up. Why does it inherit the `restaurantlist` part of the url (as if its a child view of this component or something) and how can I get rid of it? Does it have something to do with how I define my links for to the `restaurantlist` component:

```
<a [routerLink]="'/restaurantlist'">See Available Restaurants</a>
```

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Try /restaurantDetail to use absolute route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding '/' before route

`<a [routerLink]="['/restaurantdetail', restaurant.id]">{{restaurant.name}}</a>`

Comment: wow, spent forever trying to track this down, really appreciate it this worked

Answer (score 1):

A route **without** the `/` is a relative route, meaning you 'dive deeper' into a route.

localhost/main -> route to `list` -> localhost/main/list  -> route to `detail` -> localhost/main/list/detail

A route **with** the `/` is an absolute route meaning you want to go exactly there.

localhost/main -> route to `/list` -> localhost/list -> route to `/detail` -> localhost/detail.

If you are on the list page you can route to `detail` but if you are on the main page and want to go to detail you have to use `/main/list/detail` or `list/detail`.